# Ignore duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates, on-duplicate-key

```
Column1
1
1
2
3
4
4
4
5
```

Is there a way to query that column and only return

```
2
3
5
```

If I use Select Distinct it will return

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

How can I write a select statement that if there is a duplicity not to select just one but to completely ignore both/all rows with that value? But this is a single column being selected in a table on the right side of a Left Join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT a.column1 
FROM   (SELECT column1, 
               Count(*) cnt 
        FROM   tbl 
        GROUP  BY column1 
        HAVING Count(*) = 1) a
```

**Result**

```
| COLUMN1 |
-----------
|       2 |
|       3 |
|       5 |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fb00/1)

Comment: I think you mean having count(*) = 1

Comment: Updated question It posted without the full question.

Comment: @user2140261 You would use `NOT IN`. See [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx). Here's a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c8b2/1)

Comment: You have answered this to the best of your ability based on the question I asked I have accepted this as the answer. And proceeded to ask the question I meant to ask in another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420520/left-join-where-the-right-table-has-having-count-1

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Column1
FROM YourTable
GROUP By Column1
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

### [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36875/1)