# Left Join Where the right table has Having Count = 1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates

Table 1:

```
ID     Values
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
```

Table 2:

```
ID    Values
1     1
1     2
1     2
2     4
4     5
4     6
```

I need a result to be:

```
ID    Table 1 Values    Table 2 Values
1     1                 1
2     2                 4
3     3                         *This is blank because Table 2 doesn't have ID 3
4     4                 5
4     4                 6
```

Notice the Exclusion of the rows in table 2 Where the Values are duplicated ( ID 1 and Value 2). Yet the 2 rows for ID 4 because both values from Table 2 for ID 4 do not have duplicity.

So this is a left join and I want only the Value from table 2 where that Value is not duplicated AND the ID matches an ID from Table 1.

Comment: what's the question? It's not clear why certain data is excluded. Why isn't there a row with `1 1 2`?

Comment: AS stated they are duplicate values ID = 1 AND Value = 2

Comment: It seems to me like the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c8b2/1) from your previous question solves this.

Comment: The demo only returns 1 and 4 not ALL values from Tbl1

Comment: @user2140261 you stated that very poorly. Hard to help without even an attempt at writing your SQL

Answer (score 2):

Use a CTE over table 2, and then use that as the right side of your left join:

```
WITH t2 AS (
    SELECT ID, Values FROM [Table 2]
    GROUP BY ID, Values
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Values [Table 1 Values], t2.Values [Table 2 Values]
    FROM [Table 1] t1
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```